# search_results not working in ipython

Tags: python, twitter, social-networking, twython

Well i am new to ipython and twython concepts and currently working on  twython 2.5.4
now when i give the following code snippet

```
In [101]: search_results = twitter.searchTwitter(q="moon", rpp="50")
```

it gives me the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/vishal/<ipython-input-101-8f8e03087947> in <module>()
----> 1 search_results = twitter.searchTwitter(q="moon", rpp="50")

AttributeError: 'Twython' object has no attribute 'searchTwitter'.
```

Well what can be the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the command "searchTwitter" doesn't exist.

The correct way to write this piece of code would be:

`twitter = Twython()`

search_results = twitter.search(q="moon", page="50")

Comment: hi mimetist Thanks but when i am writing as per your suggestion i am getting the following error

Comment: /home/vishal/<ipython-input-150-acd13f49ebdf> in <module>()
----> 1 search_results=twitter.search(q="man", page="1")

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.4-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.pyc in search(self, **kwargs)
    365         """
    366 
--> 367         return self.get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json', params=kwargs)
    368 
    369     def searchGen(self, search_query, **kwargs):

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.4-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.pyc in get(self, endpoint, params, version)
    236 
    237     def get(self, endpoint, params=None, version='1.1'):
--> 238         return self.request(endpoint, params=params, version=version)
    239 
    240     def post(self, endpoint, params=None, files=None, version='1.1'):

Comment: usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.4-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.pyc in request(self, endpoint, method, params, files, version)
    231             url = '%s/%s.json' % (self.api_url % version, endpoint)
    232 
--> 233         content = self._request(url, method=method, params=params, files=files, api_call=url)
    234 
    235         return content

Comment: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twython-2.5.4-py2.7.egg/twython/twython.pyc in _request(self, url, method, params, files, api_call)
    208             raise exceptionType(error_msg,
    209                                 error_code=response.status_code,
--> 210                                 retry_after=response.headers.get('retry-after'))
    211 
    212         # if we have a json error here, then it's not an official TwitterAPI error

Comment: TwythonError: 'Bad Request: The request was invalid. An accompanying error message will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during rate limiting. -- An error occurred processing your request.

Comment: is it because i have to provide authentication details or anything else is required